# Why does the Server need access to Kerberos?

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, spnego

I am trying to find out how to authenticate Active Directory users to a remote server.

The goal is to use SPNEGO to receive a Kerberos ticket. The Kerberos ticket can then be decrypted and the identity of the user can be estabilished.

What I do not understand, is why access between server and Kerberos is required. Since the Service Ticket contains the client identity and is encrypted by the TGS private key, the Server does not need access to the Kerberos TGS. It can just decrypt the Ticket and know the user identity.
Can anybody explain to me why it is necessary?

http://www.adopenstatic.com/cs/blogs/ken/archive/2007/01/16/1054.aspx

Any schemes like Identity Providers or WIF does not seem necessary to me if all I want is a client identity.

Comment: Did you validate your assumption in a Wireshark session?

Comment: @Michael-O: this is an architecture for a potential client; I cannot use wireshark since the system does not exist yet.

Comment: This is though :-d Did you check Wikipedia and stuff to see how Kerberos works? In general, the service ticket is encryped by the KDC with the secret key of the service. The service does not need to contact the KDC to decrypt an incoming ticket. The RFC documents this process: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4120#section-3.2

Comment: Just a thought: in a lot of Identity federation systems, the client id is actually a random nonce that is only known to the IdentityProvider. This way, the user can choose to not give his identity to a server, while still proving that he is a member of the specific organization. Could something like this be happening in Active Directory?

Comment: Actually, there is an nonce involved but the client request contains the principal name. Kerberos is about principals. Consider that Kerberos is a defacto standard in ID management in enterprises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there are a bunch of answers to this question...I won't even attempt to cover all of them here (partly for brevity reasons, partly because the details have become hazy and I don't remember them all :)).
I'll cover the big two that come to mind, but again, there are more.

First, you are speaking of round trips to the DC as if it is all about Kerb as the DC is the KDC. I guess that's one way to look at it, but the overall Windows auth stack does far more than just validate Kerb tickets. For example, things like SID resolution are required in order to make heads or tails out of tickets that come in when making authz decisions. So communication happens back to the DC (which is a KDC and more) for many reasons and using many protocols, some of which are supporting the authz stack which is what is typically interesting for most folks.

Second, for Kerb specifically...there are some features of the protocol where going back to the KDC has security value. PAC validation is the first that comes to mind. I'd suggest reading up on this...here's one of a zillion posts that cover it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/openspecification/archive/2009/04/24/understanding-microsoft-kerberos-pac-validation.aspx
I would note that in this case, there are things you can do to actually disable this downstream->KDC flow (like giving the principal TCB). These things are not to be done lightly though...ie, it's more than just a "perf fix" to consider. :)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am having a hard time separating Authentication and Authorization in your response. All reasons given for contacting the remote AD is to verify the permissions associated to the ticket (or to verify impersonation). In my usecase, I just want to verify the *identity*, nothing more.

Comment: Yes, and the stack is really designed for people doing both IMO. Things like PAC validation probably have no use to you but yet the stack does them under the hood.

Comment: Maybe I could adapt an opensource implementation to tear out all that is Authorization and hope it works. Anyway, the message was received loud and clear: not for the feable-minded and beware of security issues.

Comment: If you want to chat in more depth feel free to hit me over email (my profile has my website, which in turn has my email address) and I'm happy to chat more.

If you are willing to write a bunch of native code, you can make it work anywhere. But it would require taking control of client behaviors.

Comment: I should add that some of these behaviors, like PAC validation, do have config knobs. So maybe you can config enough off & use the APIs just right to make it work well for you...but it'd take some real investigation...