# Kerberos/SPNEGO : multiple SPNs for the same AD account

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, tomcat8, jaas, spnego

Deploying the same HTTP based application on several web servers (`srv1`, `srv2`, etc). Protecting the application with SPNEGO auth. The servers are Linux and AD doesn't know of their existence, i.e. they are not joined to the domain. I've got the whole SPNEGO working smoothly on a single host. Now moving on to the subsequent hosts.

Most guides I've found will tell you that you need

1. An account in AD
2. A SPN
3. A keytab (generated on the AD server and then
   moved to the Linux host)

While I believe that (2) + (3) will always need to be per-server, I'm somewhat uncertain about (1). Can I do with only one account? I would really like to not having all these accounts in AD if I can do with only one.

[This blog](http://blogs.nologin.es/rickyepoderi/index.php?/archives/104-Two-Tips-about-Kerberos.html) has a good recipe for how it can be done: The first invocation of `ktpass` (for `srv1`) should be as described in the all the guides you find on the internet, however subsequent invocations (for `srv2`, `srv3`, etc) should be using the -setpass and -setupn options.

However I've found that when one uses the `ktpass.exe` tool the account's `userPrincipalName` attribute changes to become as given by princ argument from the last invocation of `ktpass`. So the name of the srv, e.g. `srv3` is coded into the name and the name of the account will therefore basically change with each invocation of ktpass. When the web server performs the final step in the SPNEGO chain of events, which is to contact AD using the keytab as credentials, it will look for an account in AD with a `userPrincipalName` equal to the SPN and this step will therefore fail. ([source](https://devcentral.f5.com/questions/apm-how-to-create-a-keytab-file-with-multiple-spns), scroll to last post, list item 3). Contradicting this is that I'm using Tomcat and thereby JAAS and as far as I understand I can [hardcode the principal name to use in my `jaas.conf` file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/security/jaas/spec/com/sun/security/auth/module/Krb5LoginModule.html) thereby effectively ignoring the principal name from the keytab.

Can multiple app servers + single account in AD ever work and if so how?

Comment: Not sure about your reasoning -- the JAAS config file defines which principal (explicitly) and which "hashed passwords" (from the keytab file) your system will present to the KDC. In your case the KDC is Active Directory, and AD does **not** use the principal as an account ID. That's the point of the `setspn`command: defining a 1..N mapping between an account ID and a (list of) SPNs. I guess the `userPrincipalName` LDAP field is just the tip of the iceberg... and AD uses something else to resolve the principal against the actual ID.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps my problem is that I don't really understand what is going on in that final step between Tomcat and AD.

Comment: It's rather what happens *inside* AD that matters -- Tomcat just connects to port 88 and does regular Kerberos stuff, just as if it was a MIT Kerberos service and not a Microsoft creature.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter. As it turns out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726864/why-does-the-server-need-access-to-kerberos) is what I cannot get my head around. I don't think the guy really gets an answer. Tomcat can just extract the username from the Service Ticket and doesn't really need the AD to establish user's identity. Right? There seems to be [scenarios](http://www.adopenstatic.com/cs/blogs/ken/archive/2007/01/16/1054.aspx) out there where indeed that step is unnecessary. Perhaps it has to do if the web server host is joined to the domain or not ?

Comment: I guess the Kerberos protocol assumes that the ticket could be **forged**, so that the server cannot "accept" the ticket without checking it against the KDC *(just like it should check a client SSL certificate against the Certificate Revocation List)*. On the same line, authentication will fail if the system clock of client, server and KDC are not in sync (could be a Replay attack using an old ticket that was sniffed by an attacker!!)

Comment: @peterh Did you look at my answer?

Comment: @peterh - It is the underlying GSSAPI, rather than Tomcat, which extracts the username from the Kerberos Service Ticket.  At this point in the authentication process, the user has already proven their identity to AD (technically - to the KDC), otherwise they would not have a service ticket in the first place.  It doesn't matter whether the Tomcat server is joined to the AD domain or not, because for non-Microsoft web servers, it is the keytab which de-crypts the service ticket to expose the user credentials.

Comment: @ToddHeron. Got it. Why then in the setup does Tomcat (or GSSAPI) need to know how to contact AD?

Comment: Great question.  That's in case of fallback authentication to NTLM.  NTLM is also an HTTP "Negotiate" protocol handled by GSSAPI.  However, the biggest drawback to NTLM in my opinion is that it it is "heavy" on Active Directory domain controllers.   Each NTLM authentication attempt by a client to an application server in an Active Directory domain will require verification by the app server to the domain controller in order to authenticate the user, unlike in Kerberos, where the app server tells the client to go get a ticket on its own to prove identity during the SPENGO/Negotiate procedure.

Comment: @ToddHeron. Thanks. Makes sense. I gotta try this to prove your point:  on a working installation, i.e. one where Kerberos succeeds, change in on server-side `krb.ini` file so that the address of the KDC is misconfigured. This shouldn't have any effect then.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience configuring Non-Microsoft systems for NTLM failback if Kerberos fails.  Mostly, NTLM has been deprecated.  It is disabled by default on fresh installations of Windows Active Directory 2008 and above at a system level.  You'll need to setup network monitoring traces to tell what is happening for certain.

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes it will work and I will tell you how. First of all let's clarify some things and some statements not properly described in your question or the comments:

You have three machines which serve the same DNS name, this means that you either have a DNS round-robin: service.example.com will returned a shuffled list if IPs or a load-balancer (hard of sort) will only one IP for the A record depending on the load. For Kerberos, both setups are equal in the outcome.
Now, you cannot say that the AD does not know the existence of a service or a server if you require Kerberos authentication. It will and **must** know otherwise it cannot create service tickets for your clients which they pass on to the server. Additionally, Tomcat [will *not* contact](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/f/f5/Kerberos_german.svg) the KDC to accept the security context because the service ticket is encrypted with the account's long-term key.

Here is the approach: You have already figured out that one SPN can be bound to one machine, multiple bindings are not allowed. This is the case when you have the machine name bound to the machine account (`srv1$`, etc.). You need a **service account**. The service account is a regular account without password expiration, e.g., `my-service@EXAMPLE.COM`. For this account, you will bind your `CNAME` or `A` record. Have you Tomcat authenticator to accept all securty contexts with this service account and it will work.

How to create this magical service account on a Unix-like OS?
Use [`mskutil`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/msktutil/) to

1. create the service account,
2. create a keytab for that service account,
3. bind your SPN to that service account and have the keytab updated.

After that you will have a keytab suitable for your use. Verify with an LDAP query (e.g., with Softerra's LDAP browser or else) that the account exists, the SPN (`servicePrincipalName`) is bound to that account and you are done.

Important: if any of your clients use MIT Kerberos or Heimdal, you **must** set `rdns = false` your your `krb5.conf`.

Godspeed!

Comment: Actually I didn't say the three servers have the same name in DNS. You linked picture is not representative of how Tomcat does it. It *will* contact AD. Why I don't know. Lastly re. the service account you say: "For this account, you will bind your CNAME or A record". As far as I understand some browsers (e.g. Firefox) will construct the service name from the A record (always!) so it is the A record which must be used because this way compatibility is ensured across browsers.

Comment: @peterh What makes you think that Tomcat will contact AD? Unless you see that in Wireshark, it remains wrong.

Comment: @Michael-O is correct here.  Application server never contacts AD for Kerberos authentication.